# Can you collect all the characters in No Sweat mode?

Tags: dont-starve, mobile

Can you collect all of the characters by playing in no-sweat mode in Don't Starve for the phone?

Comment: I do not believe you gain XP when you respawn at the Compromising Statue in No-Sweat mode, which means you do not work toward unlocking other characters. I'm not positive about this, though.